# How to run a PHP project from Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

When I type the URL `http:// localhost/index.php` my project works but when I run it from Netbeans it doesn't work.

Can you help me understand why?

The run configuration in netbeans specifies the URL as `http:// localhost/localweb/index.php`

Why can't Netbeans find my document root directory?

The new project wizard points to this as the default sources folder - `C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url was supposed to be

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

but you specify

```
http://localhost/**localweb**/index.php
```

in netbeans. Correct the URL in netbeans and it should work.

Comment: Do you know why it does that. localweb is my document root

Comment: What's your project name in netbeans?

Comment: the project name is PhpProject1

Comment: Try editting the project configurations and set the project URL to http:// localhost

Comment: Your earlier suggestion to remove the localweb(my apache document root) from the URL worked but my question is why doesnt it work with the localweb in the URL.

Comment: Also shouldnt the new project wizard in netbeans automatically populate with the location of my document root. Instead it populates with C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\<Name of the netbeans project>

Comment: Because when you are going to the URL as localhost/localweb/ , the server is actually looking for a folder named localweb inside the root and if it exists, open the index file there. To avoid this, you could use htaccess redirects or rather stay on the safe side and avoid the extra directory